# What are the rules for combining verbs with and?

Tags: verbs, conjunctions

I am curious what the rules for combining verbs into a "compound verb" are.  For example, is it proper to combine "guess and check" into a single verb as in:

> I guessed and checked that the answer is 42.

Comment: As long as the predicate makes sense for both verbs, then you can 'combine' them.  Example: *I bit into and spat out an apple* is short for *I bit into an apple and I spat out an apple.*  Wherever you see overlap, you can 'combine' the two clauses.  Your sentence is short for *I guessed that the answer was 42 and I checked that the answer was 42*, and, as such, your 'combination' makes sense. // Also, I keep putting 'combine' in scare quotes because I don't know what the proper term is, if any exists at all.

Comment: Perhaps the term ***delayed right constituent coordination***--and in the OP's example, it involves a coordination of VPs. Compare: *"He had either telephoned or written a letter to his son's boss".* (*CGEL* pages 1343--5)

Answer (score 1):

The rule here is clarity. If the verb phrase is easier to understand or at least unaffected by the combination, then it is ok. If it is muddier, less easier to understand, or more awkward, then keep the verbs uncombined. In your sentence, it is less clear to combine the verbs because you don't guess and check at one time; they are sequential actions which affect each other. If you guessed wrongly, then you couldn't check that the answer was what you guessed.